# Can I give a XBL handler a name to call it?

Tags: xul, xbl

Can I give a [XBL handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/Elements#handler) a name, so I can call it from my javascript like I do with [XBL methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/Elements#method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not, but you can create an XBL Method and call it from both your handler and other JavaScript. Something like:

```
  <handler event="mouseover">
    this.handleMouseOver();
  </handler>
  ...
  <method name="handleMouseOver">
    <body>...

  //and in javascript code:
  yourObj.handleMouseOver();
```